# PropelORM+PostgreSQL: How do I define an SQL-like CHECK constraint on a column in 'schema.xml'?

Tags: postgresql, schema, propel, check-constraint

A little snippet of a database schema I'm trying to define in my "schema.xml" file:

```
  <table name="hotelroom" phpName="hotelroom">
   <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
   <column name="room_number" type="varchar" size="10" required="true" />
   <column name="price" type="numeric" defaultValue="1000" required="true" />
   <unique>
  <unique-column name="room_number" />
    </unique>
  </table>
```

In PostgreSQL for that "price" column I would've written `CHECK (price > 0::numeric)`,but I can't seem to find any way to achieve this here.I've checked the documentation (http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/schema.html), but couldn't find anything on this.
Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 0):

You're using v1, but from the doc link above, looks like you're using v2,

I think you're looking for the `GreaterThan` which is only available from v2 onwards.

```
<behavior name="validate">
    <parameter name="rule1" value="{column: price, validator: GreaterThan, options: {value: 0, message=Price is not valid}}" />
</behavior>
```